# Second while loop not running. Why?

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

I have two while loops running one after the other (not inside of each other) - I've simplified the code a bit so that only the important parts of it are listed below. The problem arises when I compare the two echoed queries because the 2nd while loop apparently isn't running at all.

I read somewhere that someone got around the problem by using a for loop for the second one but I want to get down to why exactly the second while loop is not running in my code.

```
$query_work_title = "SELECT title FROM works WHERE ";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_work_id)) {
    $query_work_title .= "OR '$work_id' ";
}
echo $query_work_title;
echo '<br />';
$result_work_title = mysql_query($query_work_title) or
    die(mysql_error($cn));

// retrieve the authors for each work in the following query
$query_author_id = "SELECT author_id FROM works_and_authors WHERE ";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_work_id)) {
    $query_author_id .= "work_id = 'hello' ";
}
echo $query_author_id;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The MySQL extension keeps track of an internal row pointer for each result. It increments this pointer after each call to mysql_fetch_assoc(), and is what allows you to use a while loop without specifying when to stop. If you intend on looping through a result set more than once, you need to reset this internal row pointer back to 0.

To do this, you would **[mysql_data_seek()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php)** after the first loop:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_work_id)) {
    $query_work_title .= "OR '$work_id' ";
}
mysql_data_seek($result_work_id, 0);
```

Answer (score 4):

You've already looped through the result rows, so it's at the end and returns `FALSE`. (That's why it exited the loop the first time.)

To reset the internal pointer to the beginning of the result set, use [`mysql_data_seek()`](http://php.net/mysql_data_seek).

```
mysql_data_seek($result_work_id, 0);
```

Answer (score 4):

After the first `while()` loop completes, the internal pointer in the MySQL result is at the end of itself. You need to tell it to go back to the beginning using [`mysql_data_seek()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php) between the first and second loops:

```
mysql_data_seek($result_work_id, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have already reached the end of your result set, but you can use `mysql_data_seek` to reset it.

```
// query your database
$result = mysql_query(...);
// loop through results
while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))) {
}
// reset result set
mysql_data_seek($result,0);
// loop again
while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your posted code, your SQL will look something like:

`SELECT title FROM works WHERE OR '1'`

That query will result in an error so your script shouldn't be getting past that point.

Even if it does, your second loop:

`while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_work_id))`

is using a result handle that has already been completely iterated by the first loop. By the the time the second loop tries to use it, `mysql_fetch_assoc` will return `FALSE` because there are no more rows to fetch. This will cause the second loop to exit immediately.

If both `while` loops need to access the same rows, combine their logic so the rows only need to be iterated over one time.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_fetch_assoc steps through the results, right? It's already at the end on the second while loop, so it does nothing.