# why single sql query is not working on multiple while () loop?

Tags: php

I don't know why it's behaving like that in Php. In my first while() loop its showing data but second and third while() loop it's not return/showing any data. I'm using only one sql query to get same data 3 times.

Do you know why it's not showing data in second and third while loop in php ?

```
$query =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contact_details ORDER BY family_name LIMIT 10");

while($a=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    echo $fname = $a['family_name'];
    echo "<br/>";
}

while($b=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    echo $fname = $b['family_name'];
    echo "<br/>";
}

while($c=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    echo $fname = $c['family_name'];
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Think about why the first loop ever stops in the first place!

Comment: @deceze I'm not a pro programer like you!

Comment: So? Does that preclude you from thinking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to use the same result multiple times, store it in a local array first. Once your first loop is completed, there is obviously 'no more data left' as otherwise the `while` wouldn't have stopped.

For example:

```
$query =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contact_details ORDER BY family_name LIMIT 10");
$data = [];
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    $data[] = $row;

foreach($data as $row)
  // Do Stuff;
foreach($data as $row)
  // Do Stuff;
foreach($data as $row)
  // Do Stuff;
```

Mandatory disclaimer: the [`mysql_` family of functions is deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) and will start breaking in future PHP versions. Consider switching to PDO or mysqli.

Comment: while I'm trying to echo $row in foreach loop it's showing me error message.

Answer (score 0):

From PHP docs, mysql_fetch_array returns "Returns an array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row, **or FALSE if there are no more rows**" , so second and third loop reuturns FLASE (no more data )

Answer (score 0):

Because the array pointer has reached the end it is not possible to read it again.

you can use

- mysql_data_seek ( resource $result , int $row_number );
- mysql_data_seek ( $query , 0 );

Answer (score 0):

i suggest that after every while loop try to reset the pointer to this query using this

```
    mysql_data_seek($query, 0); // add this after every while loop.
                                     //you need this to reset the pointer of the query.
```

try this out and check back if you still have problems.
this link has your same problem and is already answered [PHP - Multiple while($row = mysql_fetch_array($variable)) { } ERRORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9179194/php-multiple-whilerow-mysql-fetch-arrayvariable-errors)