# why using another functions in while loop make that broken?

Tags: php

Why when I call a function in while loop its make my loop broken?

By default, we must have 3 results but in this case, its just return 1 result so how I can do it with true way?

```
function pchat()
{
    $result = $dp->sql_query("SELECT * FROM ".TBL_PCHAT." WHERE 1 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 5");

    $r = array();
    while ( while($data = $dp->sql_fetchrow() )
    {
        $r[] = cavatar($data["sID"]);  // calling other function make 1 return result ?!

        AND

        $r[] = $data["sID"];  // with this one return all 3 rsults.
    }

    return $r;
}



function cavatar($id)
{
    $result = $dp->sql_query("SELECT avatar FROM ".TBL_USERS." WHERE id = $id");
    $data = $dp->sql_fetchrow();

    if($data){
        return $data['avatar'];
    }else{
        return 'noavatar.png';
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to pull one row at a time into `r[]` array from TBL_USERS (as returned by function cavatar)? If so, you are overwriting the array in the while loop every time. You could try `array_push($r,cavatar($data["SID"]))`.

Answer (score 0):

Your $dp in source is how implements of class?

If you used the mysql is probably a problem like below link.

[mysql_data_seek() stackoverflow: Second while loop not running. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333145/second-while-loop-not-running-why/8333203#8333203)

Answer (score 0):

`while` loop does not accept any other statements inside the parenthesis, just variables, expressions and functions. Appart from that, it looks like you want to store the user id and the avatar of the user in an array like this:

```
function pchat()
{
    $result = $dp->sql_query("SELECT * FROM ".TBL_PCHAT." WHERE 1 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 5");
    $r = array();
    while($data = $dp->sql_fetchrow()) {
        $r[] = array(
            'avatar' => cavatar($data["sID"]),
            'id' => $data["sID"]
        );
    }

    return $r;
}

function cavatar($id)
{
    $result = $dp->sql_query("SELECT avatar FROM ".TBL_USERS." WHERE id = $id");
    $data = $dp->sql_fetchrow();

    if($data) {
        return $data['avatar'];
    } else {
        return 'noavatar.png';
    }
}
```